# Winforms designer - custom controls disabled from referenced project

Tags: .net, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, multi-project

(using vb 2010)

I have a multi-project solution, where ProjectB has a reference to ProjectA.

ProjectA has several custom and user controls that I'd like to use in ProjectB.  However, when I open up the winforms designer in ProjectB, the ProjectA component tab does not show.  If I enable "Show All" for the Toolbox, ProjectA Components then appears, but every control is faded and I cannot drag them onto the ProjectB form.

Since I've already set up reference to ProjectA, why is this not allowed?

Comment: Is ProjectA built?
I have seen similar issues to this before, and have generally found it more reliable to have the two projects in separate solutions.
If you DO succeed in getting the ProjectA-UserControl onto the ProjectB-Form surface, if you rebuild the *solution* with the ProjectB-Form surface open, often the control will fall off to form!
PITA. This will be exacerbated if you use custom designers - because the designer will be loaded in to the Visual Studio AppDomain, meaning that you need to restart VS if you change the designer (or VS will continue to use the old in-memory designer DLL)

Comment: That does indeed sound like a PITA.  This is my first attempt at this sort of thing, and already it seems ominous.  I managed to trick the designer into putting them on the form, but maybe that wasn't such a clever idea after all.